# unable to switch to 'current active tab' in chrome using webdriver in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tabs, selenium-chromedriver

I am unable to switch to the 'current active tab' in Chrome using WebDriver. I have tried the following:
We can switch to tab, however **we do not know which one is the current active tab**

1. I have tried `driver.switchTo().activeElement()` however it is of no help
2. I have tried `driver.switchTo().Window("")`, doesn't work
3. Tried the following snippet.

```
Set<String> allWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();  
  for (String windowHandle : allWindowHandles) {
   if (!windowHandle.equals(<cannot get the active window handle>)) {
      driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
   }
}
```

However getting the current active tab handle is the issue.

Comment: How many tabs you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated-**

Here is the working code (C#, tested with Chrome) to work with **multiple windows/tabs i.e. two or more than two windows/tabs**. 
Using this approach you can switch to any other tab from any tab. (Code is not optimized, you can optimize further.)

```
        [Test]
    public void MultipleWindows()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"G:\Selenium\Tools\Selenium\");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

        List<string> allWindowHandles = new List<string>();
        List<string> allCapturedWindowHandles = new List<string>();
        string currentWidowHandle = null;

        //Navigate to URL
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http://www.w3schools.com/js/");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        //Get First Window Handle
        currentWidowHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
        allCapturedWindowHandles.Add(currentWidowHandle);

        Thread.Sleep(2000); //Static wait is not recommended
        Console.WriteLine("\nFirst Tab Title: " + driver.Title);
        Console.WriteLine("First Tab URL: " + driver.Url);

        //Code to open new tab
        //Click on the link to open new tab
        IWebElement TryItYourselfLinkJS = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href='tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_myfirst']"));
        TryItYourselfLinkJS.Click();

        Thread.Sleep(5000); //Static wait is not recommended

        //Store all window handles in a list
        allWindowHandles = driver.WindowHandles.ToList();

        //Get new window handle, the one which is not equals to first tab.
        for (int i = 0; i < allWindowHandles.Count; i++)
        {
            int k = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < allCapturedWindowHandles.Count; j++)
            {
                if (allWindowHandles[i] == allCapturedWindowHandles[j])
                {
                    k++;
                }
            }

            if (k == 0)
            {
                allCapturedWindowHandles.Add(allWindowHandles[i]);
            }

        }

        //Switch to new window handle i.e. second tab
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(allCapturedWindowHandles[1]);

        Thread.Sleep(6000); //Static Wait is not recommended
        Console.WriteLine("\nSwitched to Second Tab. \nSecond Tab Title: " + driver.Title);
        Console.WriteLine("Second Tab URL: " + driver.Url);

        //Swich back to first window
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(allCapturedWindowHandles[0]);

        Thread.Sleep(5000); //Static wait is not recommended
        Console.WriteLine("\nSwitched to First Tab. \nFirst Tab Title: " + driver.Title);
        Console.WriteLine("First Tab URL: " + driver.Url);

        //Code to open third tab. 
        IWebElement topNavigationCSS = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div#topnav>div>div>a:nth-of-type(4)"));
        topNavigationCSS.Click();

        //Click the link to open third tab
        IWebElement TryItYourselfLinkCSS = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) => { return driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='w3-example']>a[href='tryit.asp?filename=trycss_default']")); });
        TryItYourselfLinkCSS.Click();

        Thread.Sleep(5000); //Static Wait is not recommended

        //Store all window handles in a list
        allWindowHandles = driver.WindowHandles.ToList();

        //Get new window handle, the one which is not equals to first two tabs.
        for (int i = 0; i < allWindowHandles.Count; i++)
        {
            int k = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < allCapturedWindowHandles.Count; j++)
            {
                if (allWindowHandles[i] == allCapturedWindowHandles[j])
                {
                    k++;
                }
            }

            if (k == 0)
            {
                allCapturedWindowHandles.Add(allWindowHandles[i]);
            }
        }

        //Switch to new window i.e. third window
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(allCapturedWindowHandles[2]);

        Thread.Sleep(6000); //Static Wait is not recommended
        Console.WriteLine("\nSwitched to Third Tab. \nThird Tab Title: " + driver.Title);
        Console.WriteLine("Third Tab URL: " + driver.Url);

        //Switch to second tab
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(allCapturedWindowHandles[1]);

        Thread.Sleep(5000); //Static Wait is not recommended
        Console.WriteLine("\nSwitched to Second Tab. \nSecond Tab Title: " + driver.Title);
        Console.WriteLine("Second Tab URL: " + driver.Url);

        Console.WriteLine("\nTotal Tabs: " + allCapturedWindowHandles.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("All Window Handles: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < allCapturedWindowHandles.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(allCapturedWindowHandles[i]);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: hi amitbobade, thanks for the reply, however if 'allWindowHandles.count' is more than 5 or so, then which tab does it select ?, in your logic case, it might set the last one from the loop, which will be incorrect, because all the other 4 are not equal to parentWindow.

Comment: I updated the code to work with two to more than two windows/tabs. You can switch to any tab from any tab. I hope this is what you want.

Comment: I have tried the updated code, but it switches back and forth to each tabs, my need is like 'switch to the 5th tab from the current tab (provided 5th tab is the current active selected tab)'

Comment: When you click on something, it will open the new tab and that newly opened tab will  be your active tab. Once once you have captured that in `allCapturedWindowHandles`, you can easily switch to it and any other tab.

Comment: amit I appreciate your response, but how do you tell which handled ID is the current active tab, because only the main page or the first tab was opened by driver, further tabs are opened by user manually.